# UICollectionView as subview of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I want to use a collection view thats horizontally scrollable along the bottom 25% of my screen full of pictures and then use the top 75% of the screen to display information about the selected cell (zoomed in picture, caption, people in it, etc.) of the collection view. My question is how to go about implementing view controllers in this situation.

Will I need a UIViewController to handle the whole screen and UICollectionViewController to handle the collection view (how do I get them to work together?) Or could I implement the whole screen with just one view controller? (if so, which one?) Should I use a custom CollectionViewController with one section being my main info, and another section being the bottom scrollable part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, just have one UIViewController and add the UICollectionView as a subview. Then set the dataSource and delegate and tell it to reloadData. If it seems too easy, you're overthinking it.